# PL/SQL sync two databases every few hours

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I need your help, I have to sync two databases running on Oracle every few hours.
Like just certain data migrates from one to another every 6 hours or some?

Let's say we have:
TBL1_USERS which contains ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL in Database1

but the second database is different a little has
TBL2_USERS it contains ID,USERNAME,POINTS,EMAILS,ROLE

both are on different servers with different IP addresses with different users ( for amending the sql database)

I've researched and CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK seems to be the answer but I'm notsure how to use it in a case where there are two completely different users.

can anyone give me some pointers on how to achieve this all this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need two-way synchronization or only from one site to the other? Do you need to sync only a couple of tables or a whole database or schema? Depending on the needs you could have a look into  [Materialized Views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REPLN/repmview.htm#REPLN266)

Comment: only one way sync from the first database to the second, from one scheme to another

Comment: I assume you want to have clients to have read only access to your schema on remote site, which is possible with Materialized Views. You probably want to look into that, the Link I provided you is a good starting point. 
As your requirements are not clear it's difficult to say if it's the best solution.
There are other replication mechanisms in Oracle and their use depends on your needs. (E.g. [Data Guard](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/toc.htm) for Disaster Recovery or [Stream Replication](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/STREP/toc.htm))

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've give it a go!